# Virtuemart add to cart only shows in sub-category items

Tags: php, css, virtuemart

I'm experimenting with virtuemart, I have the default install without changes, but the add to cart button only shows in sub-categories (eg. Powertools > Outdoor tools).

I changed the "Category Browse Page" and "Category Flypage" to be the same for both, but it does not work.

Is there a setting I have to change to get it to show? Please remember this is all default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a "fix". You need to have no options for the item (eg. no differenc sizes, colours, etc) in order to display the add to card on the list page.